# ARM ELF Obfuscation

Tags: arm, obfuscation, elf

Metamorphic is a technique to obfuscate a binary and change the opcode sequence and create new samples with same functionality. In my case, I have some elf binary of ARM processor type and their source code is not accessible. Is there any way to obfuscate them and create new samples with same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, and can only post this as an answer.
I'm sure this question will run into moderation problems as it sounds like you have read the binary out of a micro-controller and wish to clone the binary in such a way that it circumvents copyright.  Correct me if I am wrong, and also provide more information (which processor etc).

Comment: Tnx for your response! Unfortunately, you are not correct. I am just doing my thesis about malwares and I have to test my method against obfuscation, By the way, thanks for your attention....

Comment: In that case I would test against a real world example of metamorphic virus with multiple generations.
What college and lab are you in?

Comment: Okay!  Since github is full of obfuscators, I want a generation to produce other samples which is obfuscated and didn't find a good generation for ARM ELFs.Do you have any suggestion for my case?